# Concrete suggestions for dealing with a keyboard without direct Home, End, PageUp, PageDown keys (Fn activated)

Tags: best-practice, keyboard, keyboard-layout

First I apologize if this site is not the right place to ask this question. Please feel free to suggest an alternative stackexchange site that suits better the question.

The situation is the following: A laptop keyboard lacks direct Home, End, PageUp, PageDown keys. These keys can be activated using Fn compositions:

```
Home=Fn+left arrow
End=Fn+right arrow
PgUp=Fn+up arrow
PgDn=Fn+down arrow
```

(The same laptop lacks also Numpad keys).

This is very inconvenient since Fn are far from arrow keys, and there are many situations where direct access to **home**, **end**, are essential.
(for example navigating through text in many text editor use **home** and **end**).

I am asking this question to know what are the best practices or options to deal with this situation?

In particular, if one would like to address this situation by Autohotkey, what are the best options from user experiences' point of view.

Arrow keys are also essential in many situations and I hesitate the following replacements:

```
Home <-> left arrow
End <-> right arrow
```

Comment: This dependents on hardware configuration and preference. It is better suited on [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it deals with a specific user's setup problem and not with UX design

Answer (score 0):

So first of all, remember that if someone uses `Home`/`End` and friends, then irrelevant of whether the only way they can use these keys is using `Fn` key, they will be used to it by now. And this is true the other way around as well, if someone doesn't like using `Home` et al, then they probably won't use it in your app.

What I'm saying is, don't worry, the users will be fine irrelevant of whether they use `Fn` or not. Also you'll probably confuse them when they use `Fn+Left_Arrow` and nothing happens, 'cause the code was expecting `Left_Arrow` (btw, I heavily advice that you not go down the remapping route, there's a reason why no one even brings this up).